# Java, best way to map objects in this specific case

Tags: java, collections, mapping

This may be a duplicate, but I don't know the correct terminology to even search for what I want, so I apologise if this is and the title is not completely specific.

This is my scenario:

I have 2 different types of Objects I want to map to each other, call them ObjectA and ObjectB. These Objects are generated in a for-loop. I want each instance in an iteration to be mapped to the other. So basically, ObjectA(1) - ObjectB(1), ObjectA(2) - ObjectB(2), etc.. And there will be roughly 500 - 3000 entries to map.

The reason for this is some methods will be passed ObjectA and I need to get the corresponding ObjectB, and vice versa. I also can not use the initial loop index as reference, it just needs to be one of the objects.

I have tried making use of Guava HashBiMap, which works, but I don't like it for several reasons. 1) This is the only instance I will be making use of any Guava class, and I don't necessarily want to add ~500kb to my package for it. (This is for a mobile app, so trying to keep it small) and 2) I need to iterate the objects every frame, and iterating through the keySet() was giving significant memory allocation. I am sure there are ways around this and it was probably just some mistake I made, but still.. reason 1.

The current solution I have since I know the indexes are mapped, is to just have 2 ArrayList's, (or actually libgdx Array's, but for the purpose of understanding logic we can assume ArrayList), and I simply do;

```
ObjectA objectA = objectAList.get(objectBList.indexOf(objectB));
```

And vice versa.

Anyway, I don't like this solution either, it feels expensive and I sure there is a much simpler and faster method, I just don't specifically know what to search for.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you provide a fuller example/description on how you know what `ObjectA` instance matches to what `ObjectB` instance? Do they have any shared properties?

Comment: It's simply that they are created together in a for-loop. So if I put then in separate Array's as explained, I know that objectAList.get(4) is supposed to map to objectBList.get(4).

Comment: If equals() and hashode() of ObjectB are implemented in an effective way, the search `ObjectA objectA = objectAList.get(objectBList.indexOf(objectB))` is as fast as possible :  O(1) *2.
Maybe, the optimization could be done during the loop.
Can you show the code ?

Comment: I assume you cannot modify `ObjectA` and `ObjectB`? I mean, otherwise you'd just add an `ObjectA` field to `ObjectB` and vice-versa. Otherwise create two [`IdentityHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) objects, one for mapping `ObjectA` instances to `ObjectB`, and the other for mapping `ObjectB` instances to `ObjectA`. You shouldn't use arrays, since the sequential search would be bad for performance.

Comment: Thanks dadivhxxx. I guess I should just stick to this then. I am not sure about equals() or hashcode(), but the Array (libgdx) class I am using actually has an Object[] backing array, with methods to mimic List. I don't know much about how Java works in the background, but I don't think optimizations you suggested are applicable here.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. Actually I could for 1 of them! One of the Objects is a libgdx Actor so I can't, but the other is my own metadata class, I could just reference the Table inside it, doh! So I guess I could just use a single HashMap for the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be helpful for you. There is an interface in Apache Commons Collections called *BidiMap*

`https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/BidiMap.html`

Classes implementing this interface have methods u are looking for. I mean getting key by value and vice versa and this package weighs about 150 kb.

regards